# How do I emulate iOS Clash Royale on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows

I have no experience with apple devices. How do I emulate iOS Clash Royale on windows? i mean, emulating Clash royale but the ios one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

There is no emulation software for Windows to run iOS apps.
Even on Mac you must have the source code, you cannot run a compiled app.

Comment: Y'know, from a cultural archival perspective, I'm pretty worried that all these games will be completely unplayable in a decade, what with how locked down iOS is + crappy legacy support. Even now, how would one go about playing stuff like Rolando?